# Notifications each with their own PendingIntent containing unique data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I have a method called `sendNotification` that can get called multiple times.

```
private PendingIntent createNotificationIntent(Context context, String
type, int notificationId, String extra) {

   Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ShimmyMobileActivity.class);
   notificationIntent.putExtra("com.****.****.action", type);
   notificationIntent.putExtra("com.****.****.notification_id",
notificationId);
   notificationIntent.putExtra("com.****.****.notification_extra",
extra);

   notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
         | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

   PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
         notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

   return intent;
}


private void sendNotification(int id, String message, String extra) {

   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
         .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   Notification.Builder builder = new
Notification.Builder(ShimmyMobileActivity.this);

   builder.setContentTitle("Shimmy Notification");
   builder.setContentText(message);
   builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

   //builder.setDeleteIntent(this.createNotificationIntent(this,
"notification_delete", id, extra));
   builder.setContentIntent(this.createNotificationIntent(this,
"notification_clicked", id, extra));
   builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

   if(this.preferences.getBoolean("vibrate", true)) {
      builder.setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500});
           Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this
.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); vibrator.vibrate(500);
       }

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

      if (this.channel == null) {

         this.channel = new NotificationChannel(this.channelId,
"ShimmyMobile Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
         notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(this.channel);
      }

      builder.setChannelId(this.channelId);
   }

   Notification notification = builder.build();
   notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

}
```

When the user selects a notification
I would lick to pick up the data I associated with the notification in the `onResume` method.

I am doing the following in `onResume`

```
if(action != null && action.equals("notification_clicked".toString())) {

         int notification_id =
this.getIntent().getIntExtra("com.****.****.notification_id",
-1);
         String extra = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("com.****.****.notification_extra");

}
```

The trouble is the notification and notification_extra data always belongs to the wrong notification after the user clicks a notification.

This is I think because of

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

But I have tried different flags with no luck.

How can I create many notifications with their OWN `PendingIntent` attached ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if the flag is OK or a problem but you always use the same request code (0) to start the same action, and using different extras does not matter: your PendingIntents are all considered to be the same PendingIntent, see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent)

Comment: Thanks the request code solved it.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept the answer. That will help others with the same problem and also get the question off the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to send a unique integer to PendingIntent for each notification.
Above I was just passing 0